# How to call a other action method and create a list in my view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I have a registration form and a grid(table)for  viewing all records..
 but i dont know how to display from different action method
   My code shown below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Bathrooms", FormMethod.Post))
   {   

     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BathRoomDetails)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BathRoomDetails)
     <br/>
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.shortstring)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.shortstring)
     <br/>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/> Create</button> 
   <button type="submit"> View All</button>

}
```

and my grid code

```
<table>
   @foreach (var a in ViewBag.data as List<RealEstate.Models.BathRoomVM>)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@a.BathRoomDetails</td>
                <td>@a.BActive</td>
            </tr>
            }
</table>
```

and my controller

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {

            return View();
        }
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(BathRoomVM Bathrooms)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            var realContext = new RealEstateDBContext();
            Bathroom Bathroomobj = new Bathroom();
            Bathroomobj.BathRoomDetails = Bathrooms.BathRoomDetails;
            Bathroomobj.shortstring = Bathrooms.shortstring;

            realContext.Bathrooms.Add(Bathroomobj);
            realContext.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View();
        }

       public ActionResult Get()
        {
             var realContext = new RealEstateDBContext();
            var rslt = (from bathroom in realContext.Bathrooms
                        select new BathRoomVM { BathRoomDetails = bathroom.BathRoomDetails, BActive = bathroom.BActive, Bcancelled = bathroom.Bcancelled }).Where(m => m.BActive == true && m.Bcancelled == false).ToList();
            ViewBag.data = rslt;
            return View();          

        }
```

I need To Load or Display Grid Only after click ViewAll Button .. I already try different ways but none of them worked .. Please help me how to implement , i have stuck in  this problem  from last 2 days..
I have use

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var realContext = new RealEstateDBContext();
            var rslt = (from bathroom in realContext.Bathrooms
                        select new BathRoomVM { BathRoomDetails = bathroom.BathRoomDetails, BActive = bathroom.BActive, Bcancelled = bathroom.Bcancelled }).Where(m => m.BActive == true && m.Bcancelled == false).ToList();
            ViewBag.data = rslt;
            return View();
        }
```

I got result in this way , too slow (more time required to search data from db ) ..

[ **I need to call a other action method and create a list in my view** ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to get away from using viewbag. It's a clear sign that you not comfortable using view models. With that said, your going to  need to use jQuery, a view model and a partial view.'

Here are the pieces:
1. Replace your table area is a div that will then hold your table that will be returned from a partial view.

1. Create a partial view .cshtml file that contains your table logic and uses a view model that will also be returned from your partial view controller action.
2. You'll need to assign a click event with a prevent default action on your submit button to prevent it from submitting the page but instead to call the partial view controller action to update the table area.

If I had some clarity I might be able to help a little more. When you click Create, do you want it to update the table or only when you click view all?

A couple other thoughts. You could use jQuery to add a new row in your table each time you create and then use an jQuery ajax call to send the bathroom data to the server.

Another feature that might be helpful is to use a MemoryCache. It's fairly easy to implement but you would need to reset it each time you add a new bathroom otherwise you'll not get an updated list.

If you need something specific, let me know.